# Difference between weeks in MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

How I can calculate difference between each week and 2 weeks ago, for a given measure in MDX?

```
WEEK MEASURE NEW_MEASURE
---- ------- -----------
 1     10       NULL
 2     5        NULL
 3     20        10
 4     10         5
 5     40        20
```

Below Members work, but only without CASE statement so I have to calculate it separately:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[12 Week temp]
AS
([Date].[Week Year].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Total Orders]) -
([Date].[Week Year].lag(13), [Measures].[Total Orders])

MEMBER [Measures].[12 Week]
AS
CASE WHEN [Measures].[12 Week temp] = [Measures].[Total Orders] THEN 0 ELSE [Measures].[12 Week temp] END
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I updated question.

Comment: @Testtest11 you mention 2 weeks previous but in the snippet it says lag(13) - seems inconsistent?

Comment: @whytheq This number is only for example.